# Grow Light Tobbaco/Chili Peppers

Tags: houseplants, leaves, indoors, flowers, compost

I'm currently growing some bubblegum chill/Long Scotch Bonnet/Jamaican Mushroom Chili under a grow light and some Amber leaf tobbaco as well as some bronze tobbaco. I'm keeping it under the light for 12 hours per day and 8 hours dark. I was wondering if it will be alright in darkness for 8 hours in uk tempature or will i need the heating on? I have an electric propogator will it be worth putting it in that when it needs darkness?

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the info that really helps! :) Looks like I will need heat mats for when I turn the grow light of. My heated propogator only goes to 15c do you think that will withstand the 8 hour darkness period?

Comment: So you are giving your plants a 20 hour "day" for some reason??? 12+8=20...

Comment: that idea failed in the end. Now bought myself a heat mat going to wait till the sprout on heat mat then once sprouted out then under grow light for 12hr then 8 hr darkness put under heat mat and reapeat. I hope it works! thanks for the comments

Comment: Ohh yeahh. 16 hours on 8 hrs of

Answer (score 1):

Hot peppers like warm soil. They will not set flower or fruit if they are too cold. It can be frustrating, as they won't look sick or die; they'll just sit there and not progress much.

We started our hot peppers on three heated tables of about 9'x3'. We took apart free baseboard heaters we picked up at the dump, and put the elements in series to cut down on the heat. Our goal was to have close to 20°C soil most of the time. By the time summer arrived, the plants were large and in flower, and could be taken off the heat.